# How do I switch between dashed and undashed styles in ParametricPlot?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to generate a parametric plot in *Mathematica* 8 using the following:

```
pp1=ParametricPlot[{Evaluate[Qin[t]]*10^3,Evaluate[PhiOut[t]]},{t,0,1/f0},AspectRatio->1/1,PlotRange->All,AxesOrigin->{0,0},PlotStyle->Directive[Thickness[Medium],colour]];
```

This works fine but I was wondering if it is possible to switch the styling of the line from solid to dashed for a certain range of the plotting parameter `t` e.g. for `t>0.5*1/f0`. I know that this can be done by generating separate plots and then combining them. This is not very convenient in my case. Is it possible to do this in a single `ParametricPlot` command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 ParametricPlot[{ Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
     Mesh -> {{0, Pi}},  MeshShading -> {Dashed, {}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Use `PlotStyle`.  Here's an example:

```
ParametricPlot[{{2 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]}, {2 Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]}, {Cos[t],    Sin[t]}}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Directive[Dashed, Orange],  Directive[Thick, Green],Black}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. This is not exactly what I am trying to do. Here is a simple example to demonstrate my question:

What I am trying to do is the equivalent of this sequence of 3 commands:

    `pp1=ParametricPlot[{Cos[t],Sin[t]},{t,0, Pi},PlotStyle->{Black}];
    pp2=ParametricPlot[{Cos[t],Sin[t]},{t,Pi,2 Pi},PlotStyle->{Black,Dashed}];
    Show[pp1,pp2,PlotRange->All]`

but in a single `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: I misunderstood the aim of your question. Unfortunately, I do not know how to solve this without using more than one `ParametricPlot`.